# Use down and up keys to move to the next and previous elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a [drop down box](http://www.sportannica.com) that appears upon keyup via javascript. I'd like to take it a step further and make it so that it can be navigated via the keyboard. Any ideas how this can be accomplished? Preferably via jquery.

Comment: Show an example that doesn't require a facebook connect please...
I won't use your site if it redirects me automatically to facebook before I can even read what this is about

Comment: What does the FB connect have to do with anything?

Comment: Please show the relevant code directly in your question, and consider showing a cut-down demo at http://jsfiddle.net. It's not reasonable to expect us to wade through all the source of your external site looking for the code that relates to this question. (And if you feel you must direct us to an external site please be specific about exactly what we have to do there to see the particular control and behaviour you're talking about.)

Comment: Try going to this page on the site instead: https://sportannica.com/standings/mlb/division

Comment: When I open your webpage, I'm automatically redirecting to facebook

Comment: Ohhh. Well, that only happens on index.php. Try the other link that I posted instead.